# Ubuntu 12 does not boot off live cd

Tags: boot, live-cd

Am trying desperately to boot ubuntu 12.10 off a livecd. I get to the startup screen and choose the "Try" option. It just goes to a black screen with a flashing cursor. I have tried "nomodeset" option but it seems to just reboot and not save the setting on the next reboot. What am I doing wrong ? Any help would be much appreciated as I am in a bit of a data crisis. Need to pull critical files off a RAID 0 so I need to boot off cd to access the RAID. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Live CDs work with RAM memory so it is normal that they do not save your setting. It is forgotten once your computer shuts down.

Why not using command line for what you have to do ? For this, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open a command line session and do your work with it. I know that it is definitely not user friendly at all but it may be a solution.

Comment: Hi air-dex, thank you for the suggestion. Am a novice when it comes  to command line stuff. Have valuable client data I'm trying to retrieve so am reluctant to do leap into an unknown area. All I'm trying to do is to copy the data off a healthy RAID 0. I don't need to do anything more than that. So booting off Ubuntu Livecd seemed like an easy move --- except I am unable to boot off the cd . From my research I think it has to do with the Nvidia drivers .